# Paypal business account Integration in E-Commerce website using sandbox

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am going to do Paypal Integration in my E-Commerce website. In the Meantime , I don't have Paypal Live Account , I am Using Paypal Sandbox account . But I am facing the following problem, 
1. I can't create Business account in Paypal Sandbox. Is there anyway that I can test My Paypal without having a Paypal Live Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that you are able to test PayPal payment gateway in Sandbox environment instead of Live account. Below link about creating PayPal Sandbox account for your reference.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried it before but It only allow me to make a personal account. When I click on create business account , it direct me to the live server , I want to create an account sandbox. Is there any solution for it?? @PP_MTS_Steven

Comment: I think you just need a normal PayPal account, you can then login to the https://developer.paypal.com/ then follow the instructions above to create test business accounts, test customer accounts etc...